# Unable to easily switch os after dual booting

Tags: linux, windows-10, secure-boot, dualboot, pop-os

I got a new laptop ((Asus vivobook 14)[https://www.flipkart.com/asus-vivobook-14-ryzen-5-hexa-core-4500u-8-gb-512-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-m413ia-ek582t-thin-light-laptop/p/itm8d1c44556be49?pid=COMFSKF9ZWGMFX4D&lid=LSTCOMFSKF9ZWGMFX4DEMHVKL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeGkx.jpg)). It came pre-installed with Windows 10 and I dual booted Pop_OS 20.04. For that, I disabled secure boot. The installation was successful but when I tried to switch to windows it asked me for the recovery key. After a little googling I realized the problem can be fixed by turning on the secure boot.

But, with secure boot enabled, when I try to open Linux, I get the following message on my screen.(in the image)[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peDe1.jpg)

I even tried entering the recovery key, thinking that might help but it kept prompting the message every time I logged into windows with secure boot disabled

Is there a way to keep a general setting and easily navigate between the two operating systems?